# Remove multiple columns and replace values of columns of dataframe based on condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe with 4998 columns, column headers are the name of the companies. These columns contain stock prices as values in the column. So, I want to remove penny stocks that is price of stock(value in columns) less than 1.So, I want to remove the whole column if its values are less than 1. Additionally, there are columns in the data frame where the values fluctuate they go below 1 but then come back equal or greater to 1, in this scenerio I want in this column when value is below 1 it be replaced by NA. I have referred to  'Replace multiple values in multiple columns of dataframes with values in another column' but my case is bit different. 
I illustrate a small part of data frame

```
df1 <- Price
     Date        A   B       C
    01/01/2000  NA  0.03    0.95
    02/01/2000  NA  0.03    0.95
    03/01/2000  NA  0.03    0.95
    04/01/2000  NA  0.03    0.95
    05/01/2000  5   0.03    0.95
    06/01/2000  6   0.5       1
    07/01/2000  7   0.5       1
    08/01/2000  8   0.5       NA
    09/01/2000  9   0.5       NA
```

The desired output dataframe

```
df2<- df1
Date        A   C
01/01/2000  NA  NA
02/01/2000  NA  NA
03/01/2000  NA  NA
04/01/2000  NA  NA
05/01/2000  5   NA
06/01/2000  6   NA
07/01/2000  7   1
08/01/2000  8   1
09/01/2000  9   NA
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't your data be far easier to manage (including doing the task you described) if you turned it into a more logical data structure ie. reduce the number of columns to 3: "Date", "CompanyName", "StockPrice"? In this case, the task you want is trivial to implement. While you don't need to do this to find your solution, it would make your R code more straightforward and flexible (eg. add new companies easily).

Comment: @Pete855217 thank you for suggestion. I have 3914 in number of rows so, when  I melt the data I have memory space issues.

Comment: is having so many rows an issue or have I missed something here? The memory requirements are roughly the same regardless of which structure you use. An added benefit of structuring your database this way would also be that you would not need to delete columns/data as you process it, and would not have to do an (expensive) data file reload if you change parameters like the trigger (one penny/cent) to flag deletion. One of the beauties of R is that it allows an high level of data structure manipulation while running scripts, something more difficult to achieve with other procedural languages!

Comment: @Pete855217 I ran melt couple of times but R couldn't complete the operation.

Comment: OK, see the problem and can understand why you're doing it the way you are!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a similar approach (perhaps more vectorized?)

```
is.na(df[-1]) <- df[-1] < 1 # Convert all values < 1 to NAs.
df[colSums(is.na(df)) != nrow(df)] # Select only the columns that have values.
#         Date  A  C
# 1 01/01/2000 NA NA
# 2 02/01/2000 NA NA
# 3 03/01/2000 NA NA
# 4 04/01/2000 NA NA
# 5 05/01/2000  5 NA
# 6 06/01/2000  6  1
# 7 07/01/2000  7  1
# 8 08/01/2000  8 NA
# 9 09/01/2000  9 NA
```

Or alternatively, second step could be

```
df[c(TRUE, colSums(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE) > 0)]
## OR 
## df[c(TRUE, sapply(df[-1], sum, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)] # as already sugggested
```

Comment: Thank you quite simple approach to case. Code works perfect!

Comment: Is it possible to know the names of the columns that have been removed from the dataframe? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Could do `names(df)[colSums(is.na(df)) == nrow(df)]`. Or just compare the names of the new data set compared to the old one, for instance `setdiff(names(df), names(df2))` (if `df2` is the new data set).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. could I form a vector i.e `diff_cols <-setdiff(names(df), names(df2)) ` and then use this vector to remove columns in other dataframes?

Comment: Yes. Just `df[diff_cols]` will result in a data set with those column only. OR similarly `df[names(df2)]` will result with a data set with the same columns as in `df2`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a two step approach. First you could replace all values below 1 with `NA` in the following way: `df1$Column[df1$Column < 1] <- NA` (use `lapply` to do this across all columns as depicted below). Next I would remove all columns that contain just `NA`:

```
df1 <- read.table(textConnection("
    Date        A   B       C
    01/01/2000  NA  0.03    0.95
    02/01/2000  NA  0.03    0.95
    03/01/2000  NA  0.03    0.95
    04/01/2000  NA  0.03    0.95
    05/01/2000  5   0.03    0.95
    06/01/2000  6   0.5       1
    07/01/2000  7   0.5       1
    08/01/2000  8   0.5       NA
    09/01/2000  9   0.5       NA"), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- df1

## replace values below 1 with NA
df2[, -1] <- lapply(df2[, -1], function(y){y[y < 1] <- NA; y})
# $A
# [1] NA NA NA NA  5  6  7  8  9
#
# $B
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#
# $C
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA  1  1 NA NA
#

## remove all columns where all values are NA but keep the others
keepColumn <- sapply(df2[, -1], function(y)sum(!is.na(y)) > 0)
#     A     B     C
#  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

## keep Date column and all the other with values greater than 1
df2[, c(TRUE, keepColumn)]
#         Date  A  C
# 1 01/01/2000 NA NA
# 2 02/01/2000 NA NA
# 3 03/01/2000 NA NA
# 4 04/01/2000 NA NA
# 5 05/01/2000  5 NA
# 6 06/01/2000  6  1
# 7 07/01/2000  7  1
# 8 08/01/2000  8 NA
# 9 09/01/2000  9 NA
```

Comment: Is it possible to know the names of the columns that have been removed from the dataframe? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Something like `colnames(df1)[c(FALSE, !keepColumns)]`?